# Create Glympse Production Key

Tags: ios, glympse

I am developing an iPhone application. I need to integrate glympse
features to my application. I have created a sand box key for
debugging propose, it's working fine.
But i have some questions regarding production key creation

1) What is download url?  (is it app's iTunes link?)

2) User name and password is apple developer account credential , is It correct?

3) will glympse integrate to existing apps in app store or it integrate to fresh app?

Plz give an advice  from the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glympse keys are used for enabling your use of the Glympse SDK to interact with Glympse servers -- Apple is not involved in this part.

1. Request a Glympse production key here: https://developer.glympse.com/apps -- This is the same place you create an manage your Sandbox key.  Once
   you have a sandbox key, there should be a "Request" button next to
   it, under the "Production Key" column.
2. The username and password used here is specific to Glympse.
3. The Glympse SDK can be integrated into existing apps just fine provided you don't target below it's required minimum iOS version. (Currently it's iOS 5.1.1)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have some more questions regarding production key enabling of Glympse ,What is download URL option in production key wizard? . Is it possible to integrate glympse sdk (For production) in a new ios app which is not uploaded into App Store ?